# Is there any GRASS command to measure the distance between a point in rastermap and another in vector map?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, distance, grass.script

I have a question about WinGRASS 6.4.3.
Is there any GRASS script　command to measure the distance between a point in rastermap and another in vector map?

I have a raster map and a vector map. Raster is mapped fire points, and vector is mapped houses as point data in same area. Now I can see the raster map superimposed with the vector map on the Map View.
I would like to know which fire points are most close to house. So, I would like to know distance between each fire and house.

I know there is GUI tool to measure distance, however, I have to measure many distances for many maps.
So, I need to know the GRASS command to measure distance.

Comment: I would convert the raster fire points to a vector, and then use v.distance to get the closest house to each fire.